Why in physics we work with metric without defining topology/smooth structure first?
I come from more mathematical background, so I always get confused how physicists
define spaces straight by writing metric tensor without specifying all point-set infromation on which this metric lives. Examples: Schwarzschild metric, Friedmann metric, and whole lot of other GR solutions.
Formally, in mathematics, metric tensor field is defined as a section of some certain bundle over a smooth manifold $M$. Namely, if you want to event start talking about metric tensor, you have to give me first, as input:

A set $M$
A topology $\tau$ on $M$
A smooth structure $\mathscr{A}$ on $(M, \tau)$

Then, you define a metric tensor on $(M, \tau, \mathscr{A})$ as a section:
$$
g \in \Gamma(TM^*\otimes TM^*)
$$
For instance, what is ($M$, $\tau$, $\mathscr{A}$) in case of Schwarzschild metric or Friedmann metric?

What $(M, \tau, A)$ would you use for a Euclidean space, a sphere, or a hyperbolic space? How about for Minkowski spacetime? The Friedman metric is just a maximally symmetric space scaling with time, plus a time dimension, so I would guess it would be relatively trivial for you to generalize the definition for that case.

The reason physicists don't need this level of mathematical rigor is that we usually don't need the most general version of a mathematical idea, and so we throw out technical detail that's irrelevant for a physical application. An analogy would be that most electromagnetism books/courses/papers are happy to work in $d=3$ spatial dimensions, even though you could formulate Maxwell's equations in $d$ dimensions. You could develop a physical theory where these assumptions are broken and see what the consequences are, but usually randomly changing math with no physical reasoning doesn't work.

For most applications, you can forget about the set $M$ and the topology on $M$ and work only on one of the charts. In this perspective, the metric has a predominant role since the (pseudo)Riemannian metric is defined by partitions of unity on the manifold. Thus, we can restrict ourselves to considering only the metric on an open set without worrying too much about details.
For the Schwarzschild metric, you can think of the underlying manifold as $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}^3_0$ or due to the spherical symmetry as $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}^{+} \times S^2$. Here $\mathbb{R}^3_0$ is $\mathbb{R}^3$ minus the origin and $\mathbb{R}^{+}$ the positive real numbers.The topology can be chosen to be the manifold topology defined by the atlas or (because the spacetime is strongly causal) the Alexandrov topology given by causal diamonds.
The same goes for Friedman metric, where the manifold is now $I \times S$, where $I$ could be an interval of $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{R}$ itself and $S$ could be $S^3$, $\mathbb{R}^3$ or $\mathbb{H}^3$.
However, there are other cases where details matter: if topological and, therefore, global aspects of spacetime are discussed, as in singularity theorems, the roles are reversed, and the metric plays a secondary role.
Finally, while it is true that many texts and applications immediately consider metrics without concern for fundamental aspects, other texts, such as Ellis & Hawking or Wald's book, consider such aspects.

Thank you for very specific details. For instance, I could guess that in both cases we have a set $\mathrm{R}^4$, but couldn't guess which topology to put on it, but now I know that it is $\mathrm{R}\times\mathrm{R}^+\times S^2$.

The standard topology in $\mathbb{R}^4$ will do the job. Open subsets will then have the induced topology from the standard one.

I will try to give a very tentative answer. General relativity is not an area with which I'm very familiar with, but I do know some differential geometry and stand in solidarity with your question,  something the previous answers don't seem to do,  and have asked myself somethings along those lines before setting on the more or less articulated position I will try to expose.
As far as I know the logical construction found in most modern text books is the one you exposed in your answer. First a set is chosen, a topological structure is selected from the set of all subsets of that set, if this topological structure makes the set a manifold a smooth structure compatible with the topology can be chosen making the space a smooth manifold, a smooth manifold admits a metric.
The first thing I would invite you to reflect on is that it doesn't really matter what the set "is", there is no meaning to its points, physicist sometimes say that spacetime is the set of events, but that is never that clear. If two sets are bijective it wont matter if you build the manifold from one or from the other. I'd wager the same is true of different differentiable structures on the same manifold as long as they are diffeomorphic. If the same manifold admits non-diffeomorphic differentiable structures then I do not know. So I will focus on topology in this answer.
There can be a few reasons a physicist is jumping directly to defining the metric.
The simplest case, an most likely not the case you have been confronted with, is the one in which a trivial topology $\approx  \mathbb{R}^n$ has been implicitly chosen.
Another reason is the following. The physicist may not know the global topological properties of the space, and is implicitly working on a local chart, a further investigation of the problem may allow him to discover the topological properties of this space. The order with which the logical edifice of mathematics is erected is not necessarily the order with which we gain information regarding the objects the mathematical formalism is talking about. Neither is the order in which the theories are formulated, so a well behaved intrinsic geometrical formulation in terms of sections of bundles can sometimes be the end point, not the beginning. Equations of motion are generally local, and you will gain global, therefore topological information by solving the differential equations under suitable boundary conditions. In a certain sense you might be asking why the first person to ever make a map of his surroundings did not specify the topological structure of the earth.
Regarding spacetime our tools of investigation are certainly local, we can't know the topological structure of the universe beforehand. So in the case of the metrics you are asking about the most likely train of tough is "There is some manifold I don't know about, with some topology I don't know about, such that in every local chart a certain equation is valid, and solving this equation and gluing it all together I might discover some global information, or just discover what topologies are compatible with such equation being valid in every local chart, for example I might find out if there is a singularity". As I said I don't know much about relativity but you might be interested  researching what (if any) topological information can be obtained by solving Einstein's equations. I know that the question of the Well posedness of Einstein equations is not a simple matter.

Why do you say, "Physicists sometimes say that spacetime is the set of events, but that is never that clear."?  What else should the metric measure, if not the distance between events?
